# Cannot set variable within IF Statement for some reason

Tags: php, if-statement

Really not sure what's going on here, but this just isn't working! Anyone have any ideas on this?

I've tried this:

```
if(article_custom_field('product-type') !== '') {
    if(article_custom_field('product-type') == 'cd') return $productType = 'cd'; 
    if(article_custom_field('product-type') == 'audio') return $productType = 'headphones'; 
    if(article_custom_field('product-type') == 'video') return $productType = 'facetime-video'; 
    if(article_custom_field('product-type') == 'download') return $productType = 'save'; 
    if(article_custom_field('product-type') == 'book') return $productType = 'book'; 

} else {
    $productType = 'eye-open';
}
```

And this:

```
if(article_custom_field('product-type') === 'cd') {
    $productType = 'cd';
} elseif(article_custom_field('product-type') === 'video') {
    $productType = 'facetime-video';
} elseif(article_custom_field('product-type') === 'audio') {
    $productType = 'headphones';
} elseif(article_custom_field('product-type') === 'download') {
    $productType = 'save';
} elseif(article_custom_field('product-type') === 'book') {
    $productType = 'book';
} else {
    $productType = 'eye-open';
}
```

The aim to to change this:

```
<span class="product-type">
   <img src="<?php echo theme_url('/assets/glyphicon-' . $productType . '.png'); ?>" width="25" alt="Product Type" class="img-responsive">
   <?php echo article_custom_field('product-type'); ?>
</span>
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong and why this code just isn't working for me? Whatever I set the 'article_custom_field('product-type') to, I still get 'eye-open'. What's the deal?

Here is the 'article_custom_field()' function:

```
function article_custom_field($key, $default = '') {
    $id = Registry::prop('article', 'id');

    if($extend = Extend::field('post', $key, $id)) {
        return Extend::value($extend, $default);
    }

    return $default;
}
```

Comment: It's a function - To do with the CMS I am using, it allows custom fields in the backend.

Comment: Please `var_dump(article_custom_field('product-type'))` and show us the output.

Comment: Getting string(0) ""

Comment: Well, it seems that `article_custom_field('product-type')` returns an empty string, the problem does not come from the `if` statement then.

Comment: Ok. But then why when I echo article_custom_field('product-type'), do I get 'book' returned? Sorry - my PHP is limited.

Comment: I don't know. Are you using a CMS (=> which one?) or is it your function (=> please edit your question and add the code)?

Comment: I'm using a very modified version of AnchorCMS

Comment: Hahaha - laugh at me! I've just realised why! I didn't put the switch inside the while loop! Oops - rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial `if` clause is testing whether the value is blank, else it will return 'eye-open', so you will always get the 'eye-open' value.

Try to use a `switch-case` structure and return at the end of the function.

```
$cField = article_custom_field('product-type');
switch (trim($cField)){
    case 'cd':
        $productType = 'cd';
    break;
    case 'audio':
        $productType = 'headphones';
    break;
    case 'video':
        $productType = 'facetime-video';
    break;
    case 'download':
        $productType = 'save';
    break;
    case 'book':
        $productType = 'book';
    break;      
    default:
        $productType = 'eye-open';
    break;
}
return $productType;
```

Comment: Little typo in your code, the "case" value is always the same ('cd').

Comment: Thanks for this! I much prefer the idea of using a switch. However, that just kills off my page for some reason? I updated the 'case's' to what they need to be. I don't get any php errors returned, the page just dies off after that code.

Comment: @JonoThorne What if you comment the last line `return $productType;`? Not sure you need to `return` anything here in your code (it's not clear whether you have to or not).

Comment: Just tried that and it brings the page back, but I'm just getting 'eye-open' returned now when I echo $productType. This is so annoying! Could there be something else going on here?

Comment: What makes this so weird is that article_custom_field('product-type') returns what it's supposed to, 'book', but as soon as it's set in a variable, it doesn't.

Comment: I added a `trim` in the switch, maybe the test fails because some newlines or some such. If it's not working let's talk a bit in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87573/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-32136494-cannot-set-variable-within-if-stateme

Comment: I'll give that a try, but here is the function if it helps: function article_custom_field($key, $default = '') {
 $id = Registry::prop('article', 'id');

 if($extend = Extend::field('post', $key, $id)) {
  return Extend::value($extend, $default);
 }

 return $default;
}

Comment: Sorry - I've not got enough rep points to use chat. I've got 11, and I need 20.

Comment: can you also post more of the code where the `switch/case` structure goes into, is it a function ?

Answer (score 0):

Spent ages trying to figure out what this was,

and then it just occurred to me.

I FORGOT to put the switch/if statement inside the while loop. DUH - Rookie mistake!